# Not able to click Search button and also select the option from the drop down Getting .ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, cucumber

Not able to click Search button and also select the option from the drop down
Getting:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Reason:
After selecting the value from the dropdown list the cursor remains in the dropdown text box and is not going to the Search button

Can someone please let me know what can be done

> ```
> WebElement Searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(normalize-space(),'Search')]/preceding::button[contains(@onclick,'mainForm:messages2')]"));
> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50); 
> wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(normalize-space(),'Search')]/preceding::button[contains(@onclick,'mainForm:messages2')]")));
>
> Searchbox.click();
> ```

below is the Html code: - I am trying to click on the Search button

```
<td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell" colspan="2">
   <button id="mainForm:j_idt441" name="mainForm:j_idt441" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" 
           onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;mainForm:j_idt441&quot;,u:
                    &quot;mainForm:projectG
                    groupsTable mainForm:messages2&quot;});
                    return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
      <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Search</span>
   </button>
</td>
```

Comment: instead of saying it didn't work and you tried , please add what was the error and what code you have tried

Comment: Kindly check the error that I have already added above:org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with... Code:

Comment: WebElement Searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(normalize-space(),'Search')]/preceding::button[contains(@onclick,'mainForm:messages2')]"));
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(normalize-space(),'Search')]/preceding::button[contains(@onclick,'mainForm:messages2')]")));
   Searchbox.click();

Comment: ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
//           "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", Searchbox);

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver); action.movetoElement(Searchbox).click.perform();

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement Searchbox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Search')]/ancestor::button")));

Searchbox.click();
```

webdriver wait returns the element , so don't find it before using wait . ALso change normalize text to text() or string()

Comment: Thank you for the inputs will try and revert

Comment: No Luck still got the same issue  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.....

Comment: @sandy //span[contains(text(),'Search')]/ancestor::button

Comment: use this locator button is not preceeding element but ancestor for the html you have provided

Comment: No luck tried with the xpath that you have given since there are 3 search button took the position of the Search button that needs to be clicked...(//span[contains(text(),'Search')]/ancestor::button)[2]

Comment: use that locator then ,

Comment: did that but again it is not working

Comment: @sandy why the button is inside a td tag ?

Comment: i found the cause the reason is there is a dropdown value selection which happens and it remains over there and is not clicking on the serach box... now the question is i tried to click outside the drop down box by using the  xpath ://*[@id="mainForm:j_idt420"]/tbody/tr[4]/td but it does not work any inputs on what can be done to click outside the drop donw after the value is selected

Comment: since the dropdown is inside the panel and the search is in another panel now this is the point where iam not sure how to handle any inputs will be helpful

Comment: please add screen shot or website link , and more of html

Comment: ok website is a local host will  the tag as I cannot share the screen shot

Comment: Search button in the panel:    <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-panelgrid-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell" colspan="2"><button id="mainForm:j_idt441" name="mainForm:j_idt441" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;mainForm:j_idt441&quot;,u:&quot;mainForm:projectGroupsTable mainForm:messages2&quot;});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Search</span></button></td></tr>

Comment: Dropdownbox:tag:

Comment: is there anyways I can reach out to you via chat as the tags are huge and can show it instead